# Opensource .Net POS Solution

Tags: .net, open-source, point-of-sale

Is there an opensource POS (Point of Sale) solution which is .Net based, out there?

Comment: do you still want it @Harindaka

Answer (score 3):

A .NET POS solution that has recently gone opensource is Oceanside POS from a company called Oceanside Software Corporation.  It is  Please follow the link http://www.oceansidesw.com/open-source.html for more information on the product.

Comment: Please investigate the Terms&Conditions carefully! ("commercial license = $19.000")

Comment: The project did originally go opensource.  See Jason Brower's explanation of how things changed on LinkedIn in the Point Of Sale Network group.